# PHP sort selectpicker

Tags: php, yii

I want to sort content(sort by first_name) from array $administratorProvider, I already try `sort()` and `asort()` function. The problem is that doesn't work, it keeps display as it received from database
Here's the code :

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker">
    <?php
        asort($administratorProvider);
        echo '<option value="">Name</option>';
        sort($administratorProvider);
        foreach($administratorProvider as $administrator){
            echo '<option value="'.$administrator->first_name.'">';
                echo $administrator->first_name;
            echo '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This is how $administratorProvider created :

```
 $administratorProvider = Administrator::model()->findAll();
```

Comment: What is in the array? How do you want it sorted?

Comment: it's object containt (username,first_name,etc.). I want to sort it asceding

Comment: Ascending by what? Username, first_name, etc? Show us `print_r($administratorProvider)` and then show us what you want it to look like after sorting.

Comment: If you are getting `$administratorProvider` from a database, it is more efficient to sort the data using `ORDER BY`.

Comment: If `administratorProvider` is a `dataProvider` then will need to know how the `administratorProvider` is created.

Comment: @topher i use yii framework

Comment: @KunalDethe $administratorProvider = Administrator::model()->findAll();

Comment: Create a `CDbCriteria`, set its `order` and pass it to the `findAll()` or just pass the criteria array in the findAll() directly.

Comment: Something like `$administratorProvider = Administrator::model()-findAll(array('order'=>'somefield'));` as quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try using usort,

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->first_name, $b->first_name);
}

usort($administratorProvider, "cmp");
```

If the sorting function is in the same class as the calling function, you should use:

```
usort($administratorProvider, array($this, "cmp"));
```

If you want to sort with some other key instead of first-name just replace it.

**Small Advice**: You can use return value of sort functions to check if the function executed properly. True implies sorted successfully.